# Using this for object references

Tags: javascript, oop, this

JavaScript and I believe all other OO languages have a special keyword, `this`, that you can use within a method to refer to the current object. For example, suppose you have a function called validate that validates an object's value property, given the object and the high and low values

```
function validate(obj, lowval, hival) {
  if ((obj.value < lowval) || (obj.value > hival))
    alert("Invalid Value!");
}
```

Then, you could call validate in each form element's onchange event handler, using this to pass it the element, as in the following example:

```
<input type="text" name="age" size="3"
  onChange="validate(this, 18, 99)">
```

In general, `this` refers to the calling object in a method.
I understand all of `this` usage, I just have a little question: how `this` works under the hood? I mean how does the method know which object is calling if you dont specify the name?

Comment: Methods don't "know" anything. The Javascript engine invokes them and specifies what `this` is at any given time based on the rules for how `this` works.

Comment: your examples contain bad practices (using alert, using js event listeners in html code)

Comment: Well, except that javascript doesn't have a concept of "methods". And that's why `this` works a bit different.

Comment: @micnic it is from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 2):

In compilers I have worked with, this is done by passing an implicit parameter on the call stack along with the explicit parameters.  Of course it may vary based on the compilation or interpretation engine, but this is the simplest approach.

Comment: Which JS compilers did you work with?

Comment: None, I meant compilers for other languages.

Comment: @Bergi, colony interpreter written in lua by Tessel team, it is an incomplete JS implementation, checkout this file https://github.com/tessel/runtime/blob/master/src/colony/lua/colony-js.lua "this" is the first argument in functions